# define "finally"-action after tests are cancelled

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, unit-testing

How can i define an action which will be executed when i manually stop/cancel a unit-test-execution in visual studio?

Background:

We have built a c#-backend-library for our solution which writes several objects in our database (ms-sql-server). then we wrote some unit-tests for this library. we want to test the complete persistence-process, so the unit tests are doing following things:

-Create a temporary test-database with unique name (eg "projectName_Test_21c7d8d3") for the test-cases. (Because the unit-tests may obviously not write data in the production-system-database.)

-Add some objects to the database (and change/remove them).

-Delete the temporary database at the end.

This works great. But: The tests last some minutes. Every day it happens that a developer starts the tests, and cancels it manually before the test is finished (eg because he found a "red testcase" and want to fix it instead of seeing the results of the other tests). So the temporary database will not be deleted at the end of the tests and must be deleted manually.

How can this delete-database-process be automated (or general improved)?

Comment: You could look at using the [TestCleanUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute.aspx) attribute or [ClassCleanUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute.aspx)

Comment: There *are* database unit testing frameworks like [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/) and [DbUnit](http://tsqlt.org/). Transactions are the easiest way to isolate and rollback database changes, as they can even roll back DDL changes. *Database Snapshots* are another great way to isolate tests, without creating a new database each time

Comment: I'd be looking to see if you can pick some means by which the database names can be deterministic (e.g. if its acceptable to say "you can't run unit tests for multiple branches at the same time" then some combination of user/project/machine should be sufficient). You can then drop it at the start rather than trying to clean up afterwards. That also handles sudden power loss, which, for some reason, the universe never allows lots of additional code to be run before the power actually goes out.

Comment: I'll add [DbFit](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/) to the list of db unit testing framework

Answer (score 0):

What you describe are (technically) not unit tests. Unit tests are meant to run completely in memory, without accessing any external resources such as the filesystem, the database and so on. And of course they are supposed to run fast.

If you really want to go down that path, what you can do is add the clean up code at the beginning of the setup process. Something along the lines of (pseudocode):

```
if temp database already exists:
    delete/cleanup database 
create database
populate database
```

It's best to run cleanup code before everything else, because otherwise you cannot guarantee it will be executed. If you try to leave it at the end and VS crashes before it runs it or you simply stop your unit tests, then your database will remain in an invalid state.

Comment: "Unit tests are meant to run completely in memory, without accessing any external resources such as the filesystem, the database and so on" Tjhat´s not true. A unit is just the system under test, no matter how big it is. There are plenty of tests that also have DB-access or other heavy operation.

Comment: This is a very narrow and at the same time extremely vague of unit tests.  What is *external*? Extrernal to whom? What is the *unit* we are testing? Are the *rules* of a rule-engine external to the rule engine because they aren't *hard-coded*?  How about all those database unit test frameworks? Some of which are written in c#, some in T-SQL.

Comment: As for cleanup, databases have transactions which are superior to cleanup code. They are *guaranteed* to rollback when the test finishes, even if the machine crashes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can read in my post what _external_ is. And it varies on a case by case basis. Also OP is concerned about DB creation/deletion, not about your typical transactions.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Then you're moving into the realm of integration tests.

Comment: @async I've read a lot of articles and blog posts for the people that actually created unit testings, way back in the 00s, 10s etc. Purity wars are a new phenomenon, as people learn about Unit Testing terms without the surrounding discussion. There are a lot of database unit testing frameworks already like tSQLt, and DbFit, a lot of database extensions for other unit testing frameworks like DbUnit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not engaging in any dogmatic discussions or purity wars. I slightly rephrased my first sentence to avoid that impression. At the end of the day you should implement what works best in your case and in your team, but when you start involving database calls, API calls, filesystem calls and other potentially complex interactions with other systems, services or resources, it's worth pointing out you're moving towards integration tests. And your testing strategy may have to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a SQL stored procedure to delete the unique-name testing database. For example, a stored procedure that take the database name/schema name and remove it completely from the database server.
2. Estimate the time for the test-cases to finish, for example if it take 20 minutes to execute the whole test-suites, then it means that you have to wait about 30 minutes or so to start deleting the temporary testing database/schema.
3. When you cancel the test process, your test launcher just has to create a job which call the stored proc (in .1 )in the sql server scheduler, and ask the system to start it 30 minutes later.